# making pandas multiple data frames with multi-indexed columns and join altogether

Tags: pandas, join, reduce, multi-index

Some would say this needs to be two separate questions, but they are inter-related so I just write them all here.

**1. Making multi-indexed columns**

I have three data frames:

```
data_large = pd.DataFrame({"name":["a", "b", "c"], "sell":[10, 60, 50], "buy":[20, 30, 40]})
data_mini = pd.DataFrame({"name":["b", "c", "d"], "sell":[60, 20, 10], "buy":[30, 50, 40]})
data_topix = pd.DataFrame({"name":["a", "b", "c"], "sell":[10, 80, 0], "buy":[70, 30, 40]})
```

But first of all, I want to make their columns multi-indexed like below.

[image]

This is what I tried, but doesn't work as expected. `name` gets under the index level `Nikkei225Large`

```
iterables = [['Nikkei225Large'], ['name', 'buy', 'sell']]
index_large = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['product', 'sell_buy'])
data_large.columns = index_large
```

[image]

**2. Joining multiple pandas with multi-indexed columns, for ex. using `reduce`**

Next, outer-join the three data frames altogether on the column `name`. The expected output is:
[image]

For now, I just join them using `reduce` like below, but I want to do it with multi-indexed columns.

```
from functools import reduce
dfs = {0: data_large, 1: data_mini, 2: data_topix}

def agg_df(dfList):
    df_agged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, 
                                                   left_index=True, right_index=True, 
                                                   on='name',
                                                   how='outer'), dfList)
    return df_agged

df_final = agg_df(dfs.values())
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do this using `pd.concat` with `keys` parameter:

```
df_out = pd.concat([dfi.set_index('name') for dfi in [data_large, data_mini, data_topix]], 
                   keys=['Nikkei225Large', 'Nikkei225Mini', 'Topix'], axis=1)\
           .rename_axis(index=['Name'], columns=['product','buy_sell'])
```

Output:

```
product  Nikkei225Large       Nikkei225Mini       Topix      
buy_sell           sell   buy          sell   buy  sell   buy
Name                                                         
a                  10.0  20.0           NaN   NaN  10.0  70.0
b                  60.0  30.0          60.0  30.0  80.0  30.0
c                  50.0  40.0          20.0  50.0   0.0  40.0
d                   NaN   NaN          10.0  40.0   NaN   NaN
```